# Conditionally select trigger event for AJAX action

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm writing a script that will collect comments using AJAX call. Now I'm trying to conditionally select trigger event for this call. I want to have 2 possibilities: load comments on click or when document is ready. I can of course do it with two separate codes depending on condition, but I wonder if it's possible to avoid duplicating the code, if there's more efficient way. I'm looking for something like (example doesn't work):

```
var trigger = (autoLoad==1)?"document.ready":"click";
$(document).on(trigger,".loadButton", ajax_function_here());
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var trigger = (autoLoad == 1) ? {
    event: "ready",
    target: null
} : {
    event: "click",
    target: ".loadButton"
};
$(document).on(trigger.event, trigger.target, ajax_function_here);
```